# SQLite Query to Insert a record If not exists

Tags: sqlite

I want to insert a record into a sqlite table if its actually not inserted.

Let's say it has three fields pk, name, address

I want to INSERT new record with name if that name not added preveously.

Can we do with this in a single Query. Seems like its slightly different from SQL Queries sometimes.

Answer (score 74):

Yes, you can do that with a single query.

**INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE** should help you: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Put a unique key on the name, this will create a conflict when you try inserting a record if the name already exists.

The default is ABORT, so without the IGNORE, the statement will return an error. If you don't want that, use IGNORE.

Comment: sqlite> INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,'test',0) ON CONFLICT IGNORE;

SQL error: near "ON": syntax error

sqlite> 
sqlite> INSERT OR IGNORE users VALUES(1,'test',0);

SQL error: near "users": syntax error

sqlite>  
sqlite> INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,'test',0) OR IGNORE;

SQL error: near "OR": syntax error


                                                                 Could you just provide me an example. just couldn't successfully use it. I want to check the name already in or then add this new record if 'test' is not in table

Comment: This has solved the issue. Adding UNIQUE to name field. Now I get SQL error and data not added.
CREATE TABLE users('pk' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'name' VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE, 'count' INTEGER);

Comment: This answer could be better if it provides a concrete example in valid SQL syntax. Thanks @Konerak

Comment: @Amir Hossein Ghasemi What exactly doesn't work? You obviously can't write a value to an autoincrement field but I cannot imagine that this is what you meant...

Answer (score 27):

If you can't make use of a `UNIQUE INDEX` in combination with `INSERT INTO` or `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO`, you could write a query like this;

```sql
INSERT INTO table (column)
SELECT value
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM table 
                  WHERE column = value)
```