# Android Sqlite Insert if not exists

Tags: android, mysql, database

In my android application I need to save data into database . The values are user's name and DOB details. So before saving the details I need to check whether the data is existing or not. In name if first name, last name and if dob arte same then no need to insert data.I am giving my code below if anyone knows please help.

```
                    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
                    EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
                    EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
                    EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText7);
                    EditText et5 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText8);
                    EditText et6 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText9);
                    EditText et7 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText10);
                    EditText et8 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText11);




                                String fname  = et1.getText().toString();

                                String mname  = et2.getText().toString();

                                String lname  = et3.getText().toString();

                                String bday   = et4.getText().toString();

                                String bmonth = et5.getText().toString();

                                String byear  = et6.getText().toString();

                                String mno    = et7.getText().toString();

                                String pem    = et8.getText().toString();

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Data2 VALUES('"+fname+"', '"+mname+"','"+lname+"','"+bday+"', '"+bmonth+"','"+byear+"', '"+mno+"', '"+pem+"');");

                                  Toast.makeText(NumEntry.this, "Your details are successfully saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779823/sqlite-query-to-insert-a-record-if-not-exists

Answer (score 4):

Check if row already exist in database or not, and depending on this update or insert your data:

```
 public Long saveUser(Some values) {
            long rowId;
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Data2 WHERE COLUMN_1 = ? AND COLUMN_2 = ?";
            Cursor cursor = getSqLiteDatabase().rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"column_value_1" ,"column_value_2"});
            if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                //Insert new
                rowId = getSqLiteDatabase().insert(Data2, null, yourCV);
            } else {
                //Update
                String clause = "COLUMN_1 = ? AND COLUMN_2 = ?";
                String args[] = {"column_value_1" ,"column_value_2"};
                rowId = getSqLiteDatabase().update(User.DB_KEYS.TABLE.toString(), UserSqlStorage.saveUserCV(user), clause, args);
            }
            closeCursor(cursor);
            return rowId;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach..

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select id from tblUniqueNumber  WHERE fname = " + fname + " &&     lname =" + lname + " && DOB = "  + DOB, null);

if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{

} else {
  // insert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always create a `saveOrUpdate()` method so that it attempts to update, but if no rows where affected, it saves (as it means the data is new)