# compare a string with a database column's values

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing an app in which i have a profiles list which is stored in a database containing too many profiles,the problem is that when i save a new profile, the app must have to check the profile is already exist or not....how to do that

```
 mSaveProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            CProfileDataSource m_profileDataSource = new CProfileDataSource(CAddNewProfileActivity.this);
            _profile = mProfileName.getText().toString();
            if (_profile.matches(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(CAddNewProfileActivity.this, "You did not enter a profileName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else if(_profile.equalsIgnoreCase(getProfileName(CAddNewProfileActivity.this)))
            {
                Toast.makeText(CAddNewProfileActivity.this, "Profile already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                userProfile.setProfileName(_profile);
                m_profileDataSource.addProfile(new CUserProfile(CAddNewProfileActivity.this, userProfile.getProfileName(), userProfile.getBrightness(), userProfile.getSleepTime(), m_n8SensorState, userProfile.getOptimization()));
                Toast.makeText(CAddNewProfileActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and the following function is only checking the last entered profile not the whole list ..

```
 public String getProfileName(CAddNewProfileActivity cAddNewProfileActivity){
    String profile=null;
    CProfileDataSource profileDataSource =new CProfileDataSource(cAddNewProfileActivity);
    List<CUserProfile> profileName=profileDataSource.getAllProfiles();
    for(CUserProfile cp:profileName){
       profile=cp.getProfileName();
    }
  return profile;
}
```

Comment: If you use SQLite : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24573979/4706693

Comment: Is there any ID or unique column available which is generated by user and not auto generated?? Check for the same in your DB column. If available then already exist else doesn't exists

Comment: @sam:: are you using sqlite (OR) any ORM..

Comment: @JeevaNandhan: sqlite

Comment: @JimitPatel  i am doing the same way by using getProfileName() but it's not checking the whole list of profiles

Comment: @sam then use SQL query for retrieving the count of same profile name. use something like `"SELECT COUNT(<Profile_Name_Column>) FROM <Table_Name> WHERE LOWER(<Profile_Name_Column>) = LOWER(" + cp.getProfileName() + ");"` If you get count greater than 0 then user already exists else doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for idea @JimitPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public long getProfilesRecordCount(String profileName)
{
 SQLiteDatabase db=this.openReadable(); 
long rawNum=DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,TABLE_NAME,"Profile_Name=?", new String[]{profileName});
 return rawNum; 
}
```

rawNum should not greater than 0 ...if it is then String already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample method explains how to check whether the profile already exists or not. This is sample one you had to change the values, table name and where conditions according to your.

```
 public void saveOrUpdateProfile(String profileId, String name, String emailId) {
        boolean UPDATE_FLAG = false;

        SQLiteDatabase sdb = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE profileId = '" + profileId + "';";

        Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    UPDATE_FLAG = true;
                }
            }

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values. ("name", name);
            values. ("email_id", emailId);

            if (UPDATE_FLAG) {
                sdb.update(tableName, values, "profileId = ?", new String[]{profileId});
            } else {
                sdb.insert(tableName, null, values);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: .i have solved using .. public long getProfilesRecordCount(String profileName){ SQLiteDatabase db=this.openReadable(); long rawNum=DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,TABLE_NAME,"Profile_Name=?", new String[]{profileName}); return rawNum; }........rawNum should not greater than 0