# Getting specific value from Array which does not exist in database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to get the value or data from the array that doesn't exists in the database.

```
 public  Cursor checkExistence(){
        Cursor c=null;
        String[] values={"headache","cold"};
        SQLiteDatabase db= getReadableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_SYMPTOMS+" WHERE "+COLUMN_SYMP+" IN ("+toArrayRep(values)+")";
        c=db.rawQuery(query,null);
        Log.i("From Cursor","Cursor Count : " + c.getCount());
        if(c.getCount()>0){
            String val= c.getString()
            Log.i("From Cursor","No insertion");
        }else{
            Log.i("From Cursor","Insertion");
        }
        db.close();
        return c;
    }



 public static String toArrayRep(String[] in) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            result.append(",");
        }
        result.append("'" + in[i] + "'");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

In the `String values={"headache","cold"}` ,headache exists but cold does not exist in the database. From the code above, the Cursor returns `Count=1` which is `count>0` hence i can't insert into table.I would like to know how i can independently check whether the individual data exists, and the one which doesn't exist will be inserted into table.So in this case, "Cold" would be able to be inserted into the table.

Comment: For your logic, `c.getCount() == values.length` -> all records are in db. If c.getCount() is less than values.length, then some records are not in db.  Although, without logic, you can do unique insertion with 1 sql:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779823/sqlite-query-to-insert-a-record-if-not-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a single query to check all values, then what you get is a list of existing values, and you still have to search in the original list for any differences.

It is simpler to check each value individually:

```java
String[] values = { "headache", "cold" };
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for (String value : values) {
        long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,
                TABLE_SYMPTOMS, COLUMN_SYMP+" = ?", new String[] { value });
        if (count == 0) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(COLUMN_SYMP, value);
            db.insert(TABLE_SYMPTOMS, null, cv);
        }
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check Cursor.**moveToFirst()**

- **True**  = Have records in cursor.
- **False** = Dont have records.

Example my code:

```
return database.query( table.getNameTable(),
                       table.getColumns(),
                       table.getWhereSelectTableScript(),
                       null,
                       table.getGroupBySelectTableScript(),
                       table.getHavingSelectTableScript(),
                       table.getOrderBySelectTableScript(),
                       table.getLimitRecordsSelectTableScript());
```

See more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) !

Comment: sorry but that wont help,i want to get the value with `count=0` which shows the value it's not in the database. Thanks for your help though